# Como funcionar o header "Referrer Policy"?

Tags: http, http-headers

Estava fazendo alguns testes usando navegador Opera (mesmo motor/engine do Chrome) e na requisição HTTP é enviado isto:

```
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Por exemplo em `http://localhost` recebo isto:

```
Request URL: http://localhost/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Em um servidor **sem HTTPS**:

```
Request URL:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 151.101.65.69:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Em um servidor **com HTTPS**:

```
Request URL:https://www.reddit.com/r/stackunderflow/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:151.101.93.140:443
Referrer Policy:unsafe-url
```

Em outro servidor com HTTPS recebi isto:

```
Request URL:https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:151.101.193.69:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

E as vezes recebo isto:

```
Referrer Policy:origin
```

A minha duvida além do significado de cada uma e possíveis valores é saber qual o efeito disto para o servidor que recebe a requisição (ou efeito esperado), ou isto tem algum efeito no navegador também?

Answer (score 23):

Você pode facilmente saber que 100 pessoas do Twitter acessaram o seu website, simplesmente vendo o `Referer` enviado pelo cliente, *note que o Twitter não utiliza o `Referrer-Policy` e nem o `content-security-policy`especifica o `Referrer`*.

Sem a utilização deste recurso qualquer usuário irá enviar o `Referer:`, imagine que o seu website é `https://website.com`, nele possui um URL para `https://blog.com`.

Sempre que o usuário clicar em `https://blog.com` irá enviar:

```
Referer: https://website.com
```

Isto indica que o outro site sabe que aquela pessoa veio do seu website, porém em alguns casos você consegue mais informações, por exemplo:

```
Referer: https://website.com/admin/monitorar_comentario/123
```

Sabemos que você é um administrador do `website.com` e que estava monitorando um comentário onde escrevi o URL do `https://blog.com`, *que você clicou*. Em outros casos dados mais sensíveis pode está presente do URL.

---

### Valores:

Você pode configurar o `Referrer Policy` de várias maneiras:

- **no-referrer**:

  Removerá o `Referer` em qualquer ocasião, independente da fonte e do destino.

```
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------+
|             De             |            Para            | Referrer |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------+
| https://website.com/post1/ | http://website.com/post2/  | NULO     |
| https://website.com/post1/ | https://website.com/post2/ | NULO     |
| http://website.com/post1/  | http://website.com/post2/  | NULO     |
| http://website.com/post1/  | http://outro-site.com      | NULO     |
| http://website.com/post1/  | https://outro-site.com     | NULO     |
| https://website.com/post1/ | http://outro-site.com      | NULO     |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------+
```

- **no-referrer-when-downgrade**:

  Removerá o `Referer` apenas se ocorrer um *downgrade* de procolo, se for de HTTPS para HTTP. Porém, se for de um HTTP para HTTP(S) irá enviar normalmente, ou seja tanto `HTTP -> HTTPS` quanto `HTTP -> HTTP` e `HTTPS -> HTTPS` enviará normalmente, **somente** `HTTPS -> HTTP` que não enviará.

```
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|             De             |            Para            |          Referrer          |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| https://website.com/post1/ | http://website.com/post2/  | NULO                       |
| https://website.com/post1/ | https://website.com/post2/ | https://website.com/post1/ |
| http://website.com/post1/  | http://website.com/post2/  | http://website.com/post1/  |
| http://website.com/post1/  | http://outro-site.com      | http://website.com/post1/  |
| http://website.com/post1/  | https://outro-site.com     | http://website.com/post1/  |
| https://website.com/post1/ | http://outro-site.com      | NULO                       |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

- **same-origin**:

  Removerá o `Referer` se o destino for um website externo a origem ou se for o mesmo website com protocolo diferente.

```
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|             De             |            Para            |          Referrer          |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| https://website.com/post1/ | http://website.com/post2/  | NULO                       |
| https://website.com/post1/ | https://website.com/post2/ | https://website.com/post1/ |
| http://website.com/post1/  | http://website.com/post2/  | http://website.com/post1/  |
| http://website.com/post1/  | http://outro-site.com      | NULO                       |
| http://website.com/post1/  | https://outro-site.com     | NULO                       |
| https://website.com/post1/ | http://outro-site.com      | NULO                       |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

- **origin**:

  Enviará apenas a origem, sem o caminho do URL, em qualquer caso.

```
+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+
|             De             |            Para            |      Referrer       |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+
| https://website.com/post1/ | http://website.com/post2/  | https://website.com |
| https://website.com/post1/ | https://website.com/post2/ | https://website.com |
| http://website.com/post1/  | http://website.com/post2/  | http://website.com  |
| http://website.com/post1/  | http://outro-site.com      | http://website.com  |
| http://website.com/post1/  | https://outro-site.com     | http://website.com  |
| https://website.com/post1/ | http://outro-site.com      | https://website.com |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+
```

- **strict-origin**:

  Identico ao `origin` porém não aceita *downgrade* de HTTPS para HTTP, logo removerá o `Referer` se o destino for um HTTP, se a fonte for um HTTPS.

```
+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+
|             De             |            Para            |      Referrer       |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+
| https://website.com/post1/ | http://website.com/post2/  | NULO                |
| https://website.com/post1/ | https://website.com/post2/ | https://website.com |
| http://website.com/post1/  | http://website.com/post2/  | http://website.com  |
| http://website.com/post1/  | http://outro-site.com      | http://website.com  |
| http://website.com/post1/  | https://outro-site.com     | http://website.com  |
| https://website.com/post1/ | http://outro-site.com      | NULO                |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+
```

- **origin-when-cross-origin**:

  Aplicará o `origin` se o destino for um website externo, se não irá enviar o `Referrer` normalmente.

```
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|             De             |            Para            |          Referrer          |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| https://website.com/post1/ | http://website.com/post2/  | https://website.com/post1/ |
| https://website.com/post1/ | https://website.com/post2/ | https://website.com/post1/ |
| http://website.com/post1/  | http://website.com/post2/  | http://website.com/post1/  |
| http://website.com/post1/  | http://outro-site.com      | http://website.com         |
| http://website.com/post1/  | https://outro-site.com     | http://website.com         |
| https://website.com/post1/ | http://outro-site.com      | https://website.com        |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

- **strict-origin-when-cross-origin**:

  Mesmo caso o `strict-origin`, ele faz exatamente o que o `origin-when-cross-origin` faz, porém se houver downgrade (de HTTPS para HTTP) ele removerá o `Referer`.

```
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|             De             |            Para            |          Referrer          |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| https://website.com/post1/ | http://website.com/post2/  | NULO                       |
| https://website.com/post1/ | https://website.com/post2/ | https://website.com/post1/ |
| http://website.com/post1/  | http://website.com/post2/  | http://website.com/post1/  |
| http://website.com/post1/  | http://outro-site.com      | http://website.com         |
| http://website.com/post1/  | https://outro-site.com     | http://website.com         |
| https://website.com/post1/ | http://outro-site.com      | NULO                       |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

- **unsafe-url**:

  O navegador sempre irá enviar o `Referer` independente de qualquer coisa.

---

Uma pergunta que pode fazer, porque tanta preocupação se é ou não um HTTP ou HTTPS? Varias funções tem como simples objetivo remover o `Referer` se for de HTTPS para HTTP, algumas outras (`stric-*`) fazem questão de não enviar sobre o HTTP. A verdade é que o HTTP não é criptografado e por isto qualquer um poderá saber qual a página você estava acessando. Se você estava em `https://a.com/b/c/d` ao clicar para `http://evil.com` poderá neste momento deixar claro, em texto-plano, o que você estava acessando.

---

### Recomendações:

Se deseja garantir uma maior "anonimidade" utilize `no-referer`, *geralmente é o que uso*. Porém o `referer`pode ser importante por isso experimente utilizar o `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`. Caso acredite não ter informações sensíveis no URL pode utilizar o `no-referrer-when-downgrade`, apenas para não *vazar* o `Referer` para outras pessoas, *uma vez que é HTTP*.

Você também pode enviar diferentes `Referrer-Policy` baseado no `DNT`, o `DNT` é o [`Do Not Track`](https://allaboutdnt.com/) enviado pelo usuário, ele tem o objetivo não ser rastreado, portanto você pode também envia-lo como resposta `no-referer` para garantir que o seu sistema não vai monitora-lo desta maneira.

*Você, como usuário, também pode utilizar extensões para remover o `Referer` em qualquer caso, "independente do programador", assim como bloquear algumas conexões como GoogleAnalitycs, ChartBeats e Clicky, e habilitar o `DNT`.*

---

Lembrando que o cabeçalho de `content-security-policy` já possui recursos semelhantes e possui maior poder de controle, como limitar conexões feitas no website (evitar XSS) e ainda limitar as conexões baseada no elemento (ou seja `forms` são diferentes de `fonts` que é diferente de `img`...) e também enviar uma *hash* do arquivo para evitar que seja alterado maliciosamente. **Ele também permite definir o `Referrer`.**