# Como implementar a Feature Policy Header pelo htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, segurança, http-headers

Pelo [que entendi](https://scotthelme.co.uk/a-new-security-header-feature-policy/), este cabeçalho de resposta controla o acesso aos conteúdos da aplicação, e em conjunto com outros cabeçalhos, como o `Referrer Policy` abordado [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194052/como-funcionar-o-header-referrer-policy), aumenta exponencialmente a segurança do site de diversos tipos de ataques (XSS especialmente).

No [Security Headers](https://securityheaders.com) por exemplo, ter apenas o https funcionando não te garante mais do que uma nota "D", porém com estas diretivas declaradas a nota aumenta muito.

Um exemplo de uso (citado no primeiro link acima) é:

```
Feature-Policy: vibrate 'self'; usermedia *; sync-xhr 'self' https://example.com
```

No [Google Developers informa](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/feature-policy) que com `Featured Police` é possível realizar várias ações:

- Alterar o comportamento padrão de autoplay em vídeos para dispositivos
  móveis e de terceiros;
- Restringir um site de usar APIs confidenciais como câmera ou microfone.
- Permitir que `iframes` usem a fullscreenAPI.
- Bloqueie o uso de APIs desatualizadas, como XHR e síncrono
  `document.write()`;
- Assegurar que as imagens estejam dimensionadas
  corretamente (por exemplo, evite a trituração de layout) e não sejam
  muito grandes para a `viewport` (por exemplo, desperdício de largura de
  banda do usuário).

(* traduzido com a ajuda do Google tradutor)

Então fiquei na dúvida de como declarar a `Feature Policy Header` no `.htaccess`, uma vez que **utilizo recursos de sites externos**, como a CDN do Cloudflare, o Google Analytics (tagmanager), o Google Fonts, a font-awesome, mas não utilizo acesso à câmera ou microfone, vídeos...

Por enquanto, com as modificações realizadas até agora para os outros `headers`, a parte referente do .htaccess está assim:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    Header always set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
</IfModule>
```

Considerando que quero que apenas o próprio servidor de origem, a CDN, o Google, a Font-awesome etc possam carregar dados na página, como deve ser a declaração no `.htaccess`?

Comment: pesquise aqui neste site "Como funciona o header “Referrer Policy”? mostrará o significado de cada tratativa, aplique uma que corresponda as necessidades do seu site.

Comment: O [Feature-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy#Directives) me parece esta ligada a funcionalidades do site como: Accelerometer, Camera, Microphone, PaymentRequest, ... - Me parece que você esta procurando algo como controle de conteúdo [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy), seria isso ? -- Se sim, talvez valha a pena reformular a pergunta =D

Comment: Então @Icaro Martins, eu me referi aos recursos que uso no site apenas como complementação. O content-security-police é ainda outra coisa sobre a qual já estou pensando em outra pergunta rsrs. No caso aqui, como não utilizou estas funcionalidades (microfobe etc) quero desabilitar todas usando o feature-police, mas sem com isso quebrar a aplicação...

Comment: Mas olhando melhor acho que a parte final da pergunta eu me confundi e enredei para aspectos do content-secuity mesmo... depois vou editar. Valeu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O Feature-Policy (não confundir com o Referrer-Policy e nem com o Content-Security-Policy), tem o intuito desligar recursos do navegador, que tipicamente são habilitados por padrão.

Ele funciona como:

```
Feature-Policy: <recurso> <origem>
```

O `<recurso>` pode ser:

```
- accelerometer
- ambient-light-sensor
- autoplay
- camera 
- encrypted-media
- fullscreen
- geolocation
- gyroscope
- magnetometer
- microphone
- midi
- payment
- picture-in-picture
- speaker 
- usb
- vr
```

*Alguns navegadores expõe mais ou menos opções, esteja atendo a isso.*

O `<origem>` é para definir quem está autorizado à realizar a ação, salvo engano ele pode ser definido como:

- `*`: Permitirá o  em todo o website, incluindo iframes e
  conteúdos de terceiros.
- `https://example.com`: Permitirá o  para os websites informados explicitamente.
- `'self'`: Permitirá o  na página que tenha a mesma origem do site que está sendo navegado, portanto terceiros não podem usar tal .
- `'none'`: Desabilitará o recurso.

---

Portanto, definir como:

```
Feature-Policy: payment 'self'; usermedia *; sync-xhr 'none'; câmera https://example.com
```

Permitirá o uso do `payment` para o host atual, o `usermedia` para qualquer um, e o `sync-xhr` para ninguém, e o `camera` apenas para o `example.com`.

Lembre-se que os hosts também devem ser autorizado pelo Content-Security-Policy. Também é possível definir no `iframe`, com o atributo `allow="<recurso>"`.

---

O Feature-Policy não tem o intuito de bloquear conexões, apenas o uso de funcionalidades.

> CDN do Cloudflare, o Google Analytics (tagmanager), o Google Fonts, a font-awesome,

Se nenhuma dessas ferramentas fazem uso de "camera ou microfone", você pode especificar claramente um `camera 'none'; microphone 'none';`, e outros, pode especificar tudo como:

```
Header always set feature-policy "accelerometer 'none'; ambient-light-sensor 'none'; autoplay 'self'; camera 'none'; encrypted-media 'none'; fullscreen 'none'; geolocation 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; microphone 'none'; midi 'none'; picture-in-picture 'none'; speaker 'none'; usb 'none'; vr 'none';"
```

Isso irá desligar *todos* os recursos disponíveis. Se nenhum script (interno ou externo) usa os recursos desligados não haverá nenhum efeito colateral.

---

*Pessoalmente eu utilizo o código acima, desligando tudo e faço uso do Google TagManager e Google Fonts. Na minha opinião eu espero que o Feature-Policy, supondo que não morra como o P3P, seja integrado ao Permissions API, seria um bom avanço.*